# safari doesn't play .ogg files, so how does it work on wiktionary.org?

Tags: html, audio, safari, ogg

Safari does not support .ogg files, but that does not stop wiktionary.org from playing ogg files. I have looked through the source there and I cannot find how they are playing the files.

Here is the link where they are using an .ogg file. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/File:en-us-the-unstressed.ogg

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When you take a look at the XHRs of the site, you'll notice, that they actually load the `EN-us-the-unstressed.ogg` file along with these two scripts:

```
ogv-worker-audio.js
ogv-decoder-audio-vorbis.js
```

The scripts are part of the [*ogv.js*](https://github.com/brion/ogv.js/) JavaScript library:

> JavaScript media player using Ogg/Vorbis/Theora/Opus/WebM libs compiled with Emscripten

The library does basically this:

> Long-form goal is to create a drop-in replacement for the HTML5 video and audio tags which can be used for *basic playback of Ogg Theora and Vorbis or WebM media on browsers that **don't support** Ogg or WebM natively*.

So instead of using native `audio|video`-elements, they use JavaScript to playback audio, that is imported from *.ogg*-files.